# How to return object in React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to get a country from a json file i am fetching online. I am trying to create a function to get a country from the dataset as to not have duplicate code, but I am having some trouble. The console.log in the get country function displays the object correctly but in the gettooltip function it is undefined.

Can anyone help explain why this is the case? I have tried using the ... operator and the one shown below.

```
function getCountryByISO3(iso3){
    data.forEach(country => {
        if (country.countryInfo.iso3 === iso3){
            let r = Object.assign({}, country)
            console.log(r)
            return r
        }
    })
}

let datapoint = 'cases'
//returns string for tooltip
function getTooltip(iso3){
    //if data hasnt loaded
    if(data != null) {
        try {
            console.log(getCountryByISO3(iso3))
        } catch (e){
            return 'unknown'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Name of your function is getTooltip not gettooltip and you should use promise or async

Answer (score 0):

The system completely ignores values returned from .forEach() callbacks.

You can use normal forloop instead.